# How do I define multiple possible data types for an array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, model

I am new to C# and I am using .NET Core to create a simple questionnaire api.

In Typescript I am able to define a type with multiple types like:

```
type Questionnaire = {
  title: string;
  question: OpenQuestion[] | MultipleChoiceQuestion[] 
};
```

However I don't think this is possible in C#

This is my code:

```
public enum QuestionType
{
    OPEN = 0,
    MULTIPLE_CHOICE = 1,
    LOGICAL = 2, // True/False
    NUMERIC = 3,
    DROPDOWN = 4,
}


public interface IQuestion
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
        int Order { get; set;}
        string Label { get; set; }
        string? Description { get; set; }
        string Answer { get; set; }
        QuestionType Type { get;}
    }

public class DropdownQuestion:IQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public QuestionType Type { get; private set; } = QuestionType.DROPDOWN;
    public string[] Options { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
}

public class OpenQuestion:IQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public QuestionType Type { get; private set; } = QuestionType.OPEN;
}

public class Questionnaire
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Question[] Questions { get; set; } = Array.Empty<OpenQuestion | DropdownQuestion>(); <-- What type should i provide here?
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
}
```

What datatype should I fill in the array?

Also, how would you define a CreateQuestionnaireDto?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like you are looking for discriminated unions.  Unfortunately, while [F# has them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions), C# [does not](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113).  So you could either make your array an array of base types (i.e. `IQuestion []`),  [look at F#](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/discriminated-unions/), or use some [third party implementation](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2023/09/18/discriminated-unions-in-csharp.html).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: You are very close to the classic C#-ish way to do this. Instead of using `interface IQuestion`, use `class Question` as the base type. Now the various sub-types get much less complex (relying on the base-class definitions). The `QuestionType` is not needed, you can use the `Type` of the question in the question collection (which I'd type as `List<Question>`)